# Washer gets stuck in mid cycle

Tags: washer

Whirlpool Calpso washer that is about 15 years old.  It stays at 24 minutes (starts at 44) until I open the lid, let it sit for awhile and about and hour later I will close the lid and it will finish.  At the 24 minute mark it will not shut off but just make this noise like it wants to go into a cycle spin but is stuck.  Can you tell me what part I may need?

Answer (score 1):

The infamous Calypso was discontinued because of design problems. The pump assembly is also part of the water input assembly. The pump gets full of lint and stops the tub balancing function. After five service calls we got rid of it. GOOGLE it and look for the complaints.